# I have a question related to List where i can insert in the middle of that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class emp

```
{
  public string empname {get ; set;}
  public int order {get ; set;}
}
```

as an example that will be
var emp= new list of emp

```
{
name ="sumit" , order =1,
name="piyal" , order =2,
name="jb" , order =3,
name="sila" , order =4
}
```

and it is shown as a table in UI.
when I need to insert in this table I need to give the previous order and then if that order exists then I need to insert that after that order.

as an example, I am going to insert an object {name ="Rohit"}
and I want to insert it after order 2.so I need to give order 2 in the UI . so the new list will be

```
{
name ="sumit" , order =1,
name="piyal" , order =2,
name="Rohit" , order =3,
name="jb",   order =4,
name="sila", order=5
}
```

order will be increased for the rest of the employees.

how could I do that?

Comment: You can insert at the direct index using list.Add(value, index);

Comment: i have a field called order

Comment: Why do you need a field called order on the employee class? The list itself should be responsible for maintaining the order of the items. The employee objects do not need to know what order they are in.

Comment: i am converting an existing app to a web application. Previous developers kept a field called order.so I need to keep that

Comment: Your property `Order` (get set indicates it's a property, not a field.  You should also use a capital in the name) is actually the list index+1. Do you really need that property? This would be a lot simpler if you would just use the list index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo(in the demo,I give "Rohit" order 3,and it will go after order 2):

Model:

```
public class emp
    {
        public string empname { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Testemp()
        {
            List<emp> l = new List<emp> { new emp { empname = "sumit", order = 1 }, new emp { empname = "piyal", order = 2 }, new emp { empname = "jb", order = 3 }, new emp { empname = "sila", order = 4 } };
            return View(l);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Testemp(List<emp> emps,emp emp)
        {
            emps.Insert(emp.order-1, emp);
            for (int i = emp.order;i<emps.Count(); i++)
            {
                emps[i].order += 1;
            }
            return View(emps);
        }
```

View：

```
@model IEnumerable<emp>
<form method="post">


    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>empname</td>
                <td>order</td>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{ var i = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.empname
                        <input asp-for="@item.empname" name="[@i].empname" hidden/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.order
                        <input asp-for="@item.order" name="[@i].order" hidden/>

                    </td>

                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    Create<br />
    <label>empname</label>
    <input  name="empname" />
    <label>order</label>
    <input  name="order" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

result(When click button,pass data to action,and add the new emp to list,and return view with new list):
[image]

Comment: man you are fantastic, i am grateful to you for this .thanks a lot .thanks again

Comment: man i have a quick question can I save this data with primary key in employee id ? will it give me any issue for primary key?

Comment: Do you mean you also have employee id in emp class?If your employee id is auto increment in db.You don't need to pass employee id to database when adding a new emp to db.

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you mark it?Thank you.

Comment: man, it is not auto-incremented.I generate it with code.

Comment: If so,you can save emp with employee id.

Comment: @Yiji can you please help me in a project I got stuck? i am not understanding few things . i could I contact you if you don't have any issues ? i really need help .

Comment: You can create a new issue,and describe about what you cannot understanding.

Comment: It might sound awkward, can we discuss that over email or phone?

Comment: Sorry,I'm afraid not.

Comment: Man i have one prpblem , i need to give the order  and with jquery i need to check if it exists  if exist I need to show alert , after that I need to insert , if not exist I need to return .how can I do that ?

Comment: `emps[i].order += 1;` => `emps[i].order++` but not that important